# References on Riemann surfaces

Tags: reference-request, hyperbolic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, 3-manifolds, teichmuller-theory

I have asked the question in MSE, but did not get an answer.

I am asking a soft question here. I am interested in learning about Hyperbolic Geometry. I  have read the book named "Fuchsian Groups" by S. Katok. Mainly I am focused about Hyperbolic Geometry, Geometry and Topology of 3-manifolds, knot theory, etc. But before studying more advanced hyperbolic geometry,  I want to complete a course in Riemann surfaces.

I know about that there are many books avaliable in online such as Rick Miranda, Griffiths and Harris, etc. But most of them are toward Algebraic Geometry. I am looking for books in Riemann surfaces towards hyperbolic geometry, Teichmuller theory, 3-manifolds etc. Also, it will be nice if it contains some exercises.

Please help me. Thanking in advanced.

Comment: This book is quite nice (in French though) : https://store.cassini.fr/enseignement-des-mathematiques/42-introduction-a-la-geometrie-hyperbolique-et-aux-surfaces-de-riemann.html

Comment: J. Hubbard's Teichmuller Theory, vol. 1 develops the theory of Riemann surfaces from this point of view.

Comment: Please include a link to the m.se question here, and a link to this question there.

Answer (score 1):

I've skimmed "Mostly surfaces" by Rich Schwartz; it may be at the correct level. Here is a link to the book at the AMS bookstore:

https://bookstore.ams.org/stml-60/

and there is a preprint version at Rich's webpage.

Answer (score 0):

You should try:
http://matrixeditions.com/
http://matrixeditions.com/#Teich1
http://matrixeditions.com/#Teich2

In the future hopefully there will be volumes 3 and 4.

Best regards!